# JS include tag not being removed from dom, even though it has been removed from the file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browser-cache

I'm building a rails app, and I'm having an issue where i'm getting two confirmation boxes popping up, rather than one when I use :confirm.

I've come to the conclusion that this is a result of `rails.js` being included twice, once in my layout, and once in `application.js`. However, when I deleted `<%=javascript_include_tag "rails.js"%>` from `application.html.erb`, and do view page source on the app it still shows it being included.

I tried deleting my browser cache, restarting the browser, going in incognito mode, I cleaned my assets pipeline, made sure `config.assets.debug = false`. Any ideas on how to alleviate this issue? Thanks.

head portion of application.html.erb:

```
    <head>
       <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- [if IE]>  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
        <%=stylesheet_link_tag("normalize")%>
        <%=stylesheet_link_tag("main")%>
        <%=stylesheet_link_tag("r")%>
        <%=stylesheet_link_tag("webfonts/ss-standard")%>
        <!--link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css"-->




        <%=javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min"%>
        <%=javascript_include_tag "//use.typekit.net/rwg2mxn.js"%>      
        <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
        <%=javascript_include_tag "jquery.cookie.js"%>
        <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
            api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE
            authorize: true
        </script-->
        <%=javascript_include_tag "plugins.js"%>
        <%=javascript_include_tag "vendor/jquery.touchSwipe.min"%>
        <!--script src="js/vendor/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script-->

    <%=yield :head%>

    </head>
```

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you post the head portion of your view, and your application.js file.

Comment: Edited to include head and application,js

Answer (score 1):

Rails will include all your js files in app/assets/javascripts, beacause of

application.html.erb

> javascript_include_tag "application"

And

application.js

> //= require_tree

If you do not want your rails.js imported, you have to remove that file from the app/asssets/javascript directory.

Comment: I second this your going to need to first move all your scripts from the head of your view into your application.js file, and then also remove require_tree . It causes horrible issues and is really buggy.